# how to input to multiple cells from different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ptn.jpg)
its kind of hard to describe. but what I want is when one of the cells in the red rectangle goes red (like 7 of them are), I want the truck number to be input in to the cells in the green rectangle. I have been searching all over but its difficult to search what I need.

I just don't want there to be spaces in the green rectangle. I would like the truck numbers to be able to be put in any of the fields in the green that are not filled already.

[image: Excel image]
[image: Excel image]
[image: Excel image]

Comment: I have no idea what you are describing so can't help. Help us to help you. Give some examples. What have you tried?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have.  The new Filter() formula will do this, using the same criteria that is being used in the conditional format to color the cells.  We would need to know the criteria being used to color the cells to help.  A formula cannot detect formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add add a helper column. On my following sample, it is on D column.

- Create a new Name with formula `=GET.CELL(63,B2)`, on my sample I call it "Color".

[image]

- Then I enter the formula `=Color` in D2, and drag down.
- Enter the array formula in your green box, `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(IF($D$1:$D$9=3,ROW($D$1:$D$9),4^8),ROW(A2)))&"","")`, press **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter** together.
  (Please note, the value of `$D$1:$D$9=3` is not fixed, it is according to the color.

[image]

-----Update------

If there are multiple background colors, then you can modify the value "3" of `$D$1:$D$9=3` according to the results of Name "Color".

[image]

[image]

Comment: how would this work with 3 different colors? like you can see in my pic. column C would input the truck #s in column Q. Red would put truck #s in Q6-15, Green would put truck #s in Q18-25 and yellow would put truck #s in Q28-35.

Comment: for some reason i cant get the get.color to work. its not outputting a number for the colors.

Comment: @ShaneB I suggest you check the formula of "Color" Name, make sure it is correct. Besides, the workbook should be saved as .xlsm.

Comment: does it matter that I'm using excel 2013? I even tried to copy exactly what your example was, but I'm still not getting the numbers that represent the color to show up

Comment: @ShaneB I find a environment with Office 2013 installed, `=GET.CELL(63,XX)` works correctly. Please make sure, the Name formula is right, please click on the first cell to get the color value to create this Name,"XX" means the corresponding cell with background color. [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbyfo.gif)

Comment: That's what I have been doing. But for some reason it's not working. I get all 0's for the colors.

Comment: i added an updated picture to show the formula i was using for get.cell

Comment: I just thought does it matter that there is text in the cell?

Comment: @ShaneB In the formula for Name, I see that you use absolute reference notation, need to remove “$”, and then use relative reference. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04bUW.jpg)

Comment: i added a new photo at top. i tried that and still get 0's. i dont know what im doing wrong? anyway i can send you the file to look at?

Comment: @ShaneB Yes, can you share us this sample via OneDrive link?

Comment: Let me know if this works. https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au3pBssZzApUhyQR0p7NUOhEL863

Comment: Sorry, I can not open your shared file, it says: This workbook could not be opened because this file format may not be matching with the file extension.  This is [my file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnHoiCikfd80iWudETXNi6kP0flf?e=MqlbJ5), you can download it, enable editing and content to have a check.

Comment: That's odd. Ok I'll take a look at yours and see.

Comment: so ive compaired your file and my file. i cant see what im doing wrong. all the formulas are the same. (just different cells). but for some reason im not getting it to list the colors.

Comment: No, I still get the same error message. Can you share me a .xlsx workbook without this Name formula to me?

Comment: hope this one works
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au3pBssZzApUhyXIp_3GY5owZENk?e=cmaHzd

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, I find that you use the condition format, but get.cell function does work for condition format. Sorry for wasting your time, I think you need the VBA help.

Comment: Oh ok. Anyone you know of that could help?

Comment: will the =IFERROR formula still work tho?